# BindingResolutionsException Target[Laravel\Socialite\Contracts\Factory] is not instantiable

Tags: laravel

i am trying to use socialite for make "Login with facebook" but i am getting this error continuously BindingResolutionsException Target[Laravel\Socialite\Contracts\Factory] is not instantiable. Please help me.

```
'providers' => [

           ....
            Sun\Flash\FlashServiceProvider::class,
            Laravel\Socialite\SocialiteServiceProvider::class
        ],

'aliases' => [
        ....
        'Flash'     => Sun\Flash\FlashFacade::class,
        'PmhAuth'   => app\Library\Auth\PmhAuth\PmhAuthFacades::class,
        'Socialite' => Laravel\Socialite\Facades\Socialite::class
    ],
```

here is my controller

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

use App\Http\Requests;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Laravel\Socialite\Facades\Socialite;
class SocialAuthController extends Controller
{
    public function redirect()
    {
        return Socialite::driver('facebook')->redirect();
    }
    public function callback()
    {

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you've aliased `Socialite` in your config:

```
'Socialite' => Laravel\Socialite\Facades\Socialite::class
```

Try importing the alias:

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

use Socialite;
use App\Http\Requests;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;

class SocialAuthController extends Controller
{
    public function redirect()
    {
        return Socialite::driver('facebook')->redirect();
    }
    public function callback()
    {

    }
}
```